# How to submit test data and post requests between views in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have a theory as to how to approach them, and was looking for some guidance on how to solve this problem and see if I am on the right path, because I am not sure.

I have a web app for a project I am building, and I have a database that I need to query for specific information. I have a **search** button that is attached to a function in my **MainController**, and I need to have my data passed on to my **result.html** file, which displays information from a **ResultsController**.

This is my theory for how to get this working using fake data, and an html request (which uses promises I imagine?)

1. for fake/test data, I stored an array with objects that represents JSON data in my services file that was basically the parent to ResultsController and MainController, and ResultsController would take in that information and display it on the screen.
2. For querying a database, my search function would search the database, and fill/replace the array in my services file with additional information. By virtue of changing that array of objects in my services, my results.html should pull down new data automatically when I click search, since the ResultsController has access to that same JSON data. (also, clicking search submits the query and then does $location.path("/results") after to get to the results page).

For querying a database and dynamically changing the information on a page, are these the right steps to submitting a request to a database in pulling information down upon each "search" request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track in using a service to share logic and data between the two controllers. This is generally seen as [best practice](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y035) - and it is better than the approach that is sometimes used of putting the logic and data in a parent controller, and using scope to access it in child controller.

The style guide linked to above is worth a read if you are looking for some guidance on best practice in setting up an angular app (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).